# Opening bash file in same Terminal window

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, gnupg

**EDIT:** Turns out I was able to partially solve my own problem - I'm not sure about the particular details, but as far as I know creating/editing `~/.bash_profile` simply makes Terminal run scripts in that file automatically when launched. Seems like `~/.bashrc` and other files do similar but still different things, but I don't know the details. What I did to fix was to edit my existing `.bash_profile` file and add the `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` line to the end. This fixed GPG/git in Terminal.

The title may be confusing, so let me elaborate a bit.

My code as of now is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "This script fixes errors with ioctl in GPG."

export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

The last line does help with the fix ([issue detailed here](https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/1712); [solution used](https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/1712#issuecomment-141226705)), but I have to run it multiple times, every time I re-open a new Terminal window. Although the script may not necessarily be faster than simply typing it, it would still help for me.

As of now, the result is that it opens a new window in Terminal, with the output like this:

```
 This script fixes errors with ioctl in GPG.
 logout
 Saving session...
 ...copying shared history...
 ...saving history...truncating history files...
 ...completed.

 [Process completed]
```

This does not help with any of the other windows I am using, so is there a way to make this fix apply to other windows, or open in the last used terminal window?

Additionally, is there a permanent fix to ioctl for GPG, or is there a way to automatically run this script whenever I open a new Terminal window, or when I use a command that uses GPG (e.g., `git commit`)?

Am I forced to either enter in the code manually or use a script file to do this?

This may be a bad or a simple question, but I'd like to ask it all the same.

Thanks in advance.